# The system cannot find the path specified wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I´m starting to learn Java EE.

I installed wildfly in Windows. 
I already have JDK 8 installed and I have it set up in my  Environment Variables as 
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
As you can see JDK is installed in the default folder in program files.

Wildfly is installed in a specific folder(is the lastest version since I just downloaded. EAP 7.0.0):
C:\develop\wildfly\

I set up the Environment Variables of wildfly too. as 
JBOSS_HOME C:\Develop\wildFly

I started the server in net beans and when I tried to enter in the Administration Console the server display a message that I needed to add a user and I should run add-user.bat

The problem is when I try to run this .bat file.

I get the error "The system cannot find the path specified"

Even though I found some questions concerning this issue I couldn´t find a correct answer since I don´t have any of the problems that the answers state that could make this error. (no JDK installed, not set up environment variables)

please tell me if you need further information.

Comment: While you don't have Wildfly (go to http://wildfly.org for that) and a prehistoric Java version, ultimately, you need to either set your PATH environment variable to include what will be something like C:\Develop\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin or just run .\add-user.bat once you've done a "cd" into that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Windows OS** open `{WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/standalone.conf.bat`

And Find `JAVA_HOME`

The Default value may like `rem set "JAVA_HOME=C:\opt\jdk1.6.0_23"`

Change it to

> set "JAVA_HOME=PATH_TO_JAVA"

e.g. set "JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\Java8\"

For **Linux** do same in `standalone.sh`

Comment: Thank you. that was my problem. I changed this and it worked